# Nuxt: using component as a link

Tags: routes, nuxt.js

I want to use my `JobPost` component as a link, so whenever it is clicked it will lead to the proper description.

```
<JobPost
  v-for="job in jobs"
  :key="job.id"
  :details="job.post"
  :to="{ name: 'job', params: { id: job.id } }"
/>
```

I have this. My question is how I can make it link?

I tried to wrap it with `nuxt-link` but this way i get one more `JobPost` component

```
<nuxt-link
  v-for="job in jobs"
  :key="job.id"
  :to="{ name: 'job', params: { id: job.id } }"
>
  <JobPost :details="job.post" />
</nuxt-link>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this sample may be proper for your question:

```
import {action} from '@storybook/addon-actions'
// import VueRouter  from 'vue-router' - not needed
// import NuxtLink from 'nuxt/lib/app/components/nuxt-link' - not needed

Vue.component('RouterLink', {
  props:   ['to'],
  methods: {
    log() {
      action('link target')(this.to)
    },
  },
  template: '<div @click="log()"><slot>RouterLink</slot></div>',
})

Vue.component('NuxtLink', {
  props:   ['to'],
  methods: {
    log() {
      action('link target')(this.to)
    },
  },
  template: '<div @click="log()"><slot>NuxtLink</slot></div>',
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use **@click** event to call this.$router.push() method or wrap the root element of job post component with nuxt-link component.

```
<JobPost
  v-for="job in jobs"
  :key="job.id"
  :details="job.post"
  @click="$router.push({ name: 'job', params: { id: job.id }})"
/>
```